# Give arguments to function in a dynamic way

Tags: php, dynamic

I'm currently looking for a way to give arguments to a function dynamically.
Some code to explain:

```
//Class: ClassXY
PUBLIC function function1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
PUBLIC function function2($arg1);
```

I currently call it like this:

```
// $method = 'function1' or 'function2'
echo ClassXY :: {$method}($parameter_string);
```

My problem is, that `parameter_string` either is a simple string, that contains the argument or an array that contains all the arguments I want to give to the function. For instance:

```
$parameter_string: array(3) {[0] => 'arg1', [1] => 'arg2', [2] => 'arg3' }
```

So far so good. My Problem is, that the call will only work with `ClassXY :: function2()` since it only expects one argument. If I call `ClassXY :: function2()` it wont work, since it expects three arguments but only one argument (the array with the three elements, that are supposed to be the three arguments) is given. I need a way to make php realize that each element of the array shall be one argument. Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: take a look at variadic functions (if you are using php 5.6): [PHP 5.6 news](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/php-56-whats-new--cms-22101)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `call_user_func_array` is what you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php